# Web scraping using selenium and not be able to move on to the next webpage

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

So I have been trying to webscrape from [ZALORA](https://www.zalora.com.hk/men/clothing/shirt/?gender=men&dir=desc&sort=popularity&category_id=31&enable_visual_sort=1), it seems selenium keep scraping repeated data.......

Here is my codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.zalora.com.hk/men/clothing/shirt/?gender=men&dir=desc&sort=popularity&category_id=31&page=1&enable_visual_sort=1'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

brandname=''
productTitle=''
page=0

while True:
    info_brandname = ''
    info_product_title = ''
    page=page+1

    if len(info_brandname) < 99 or len(info_product_title) < 99:
        info_brandname = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="b-catalogList__itmBrand fsm txtDark uc js-catalogProductTitle"]')
        info_product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//em[@class="b-catalogList__itmTitle fss"]')
        print('info_brandname ' + str(len(info_brandname)) + ' at page ' + str(page))
        print('info_product_title ' + str(len(info_product_title)) + ' at page ' + str(page))

    else:
        print('info_brandname ' + str(len(info_brandname)) + ' at page ' + str(page))
        print('info_product_title ' + str(len(info_product_title)) + ' at page ' + str(page))

    #some manipulation of the scrapped data
    for i in range(len(info_brandname)):
        brandname = brandname + '\n' + info_brandname[i].text
        productTitle = productTitle + '\n' + info_product_title[i].text

    print(brandname.split('\n')[1:])
    print(productTitle.split('\n')[1:])
```

Here is the part I suspect has gone wrong:

```
    #go to the next page before it loops again
    try:
        test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Next']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", test)
    except:
        print('there is no next page man...')

    time.sleep(2)
    print(str(driver.current_url))

driver.close()
```

EDIT: At the moment, the very last item's name should be 'Life8' according to the website, but I got 'J.Crew', and I have scraped 1885 items in total, while the website says they have only 1847 items in total.
The pages' url were actually changing while the script was running, along with the items on each page, everything behaves normally when I see the automation doing its things on chrome, just the data that selenium scraped is weird.

EDIT2: I have done some more investigation, I monitored the automation process in the webdrive Chrome, and find out that the same url in the webdrive Chrome has different contents from the same url when I normally browse ZALORA in normal Chrome, is it possible that the website did something to prevent people from scraping?

Comment: Note that it's very very very bad idea (never do this again) to include dozens of code lines into simple `try`/`except` block without even specifying exact exception that you want to catch. Also you'd better simplify your code in question just to reflect your specific issue - no one wants to check all these lines...

Comment: okay let me polish my codes, sorry for the mess, I am still very new in webscrapping/coding...thanks for the advises!

Comment: @TedLLH, use debug for fixing your problem (you learn a lot). This is not a service for writing code for you. As mentioned Andersson: reflect your specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're trying to get new URL right after clicking Next button while it should take some time for URL to change, so each time you navigates to the same page.

Actually I have no idea why do you need to `driver.get(url)` at the beginning of each iteration when you've already switched to next page by clicking Next...

Try just to remove this line `driver.get(url)` (move it out of loop) and this `url = driver.current_url`

Also note that you can call `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` just once in the script (you can put it right after `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`) and it will be applied to all elements searches...

Comment: I have done what you have said, but the problem still exist......so at the moment, the very last item's name should be 'Life8' according to the website, but I got 'J.Crew', and I have scrapped 1885 items in total, while the website says they have only 1847 items in total......

Comment: and the thing you said about navigates to the same page, its actually not, the pages url was actually changed, along with the items on each page, it all behaves very normally when I see the automation doing its things on chrome, just the data that selenium scrapped is weird......

Answer (score 0):

I managed to scrape the correct data by changing `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` to `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`, and this resolve the issue I encountered. Although I am not entirely sure why it fixed the issues.